# Seed identification

Tags: identification, seeds

Wondered if you could help me identify those seeds I received:

[image]

(the delivery number has no matches within my eBay orders)

I tried uploading this picture and image search via Google but nothing there.

Comment: The Ebay seller might be able to tell you, if they get a complaint from another customer about a missing item. From the picture, they could be almost anything - "small, black, irregular shaped, and no obvious identification features" isn't much to work on!

Answer (score 1):

The US quarter is about 24mm in diameter, and about 8 or 9 of the seeds placed lengthwise in a line end to end would about span the quarter making each seed a bit less than 3mm long. This puts it too small for a luffa, too big for a black seeded lettuce but about right for a Cassia fasciata for example.

However Cassia is a pea type creature and attaches to the pod at more of a point - these seeds appear to have more of a flattened attachment end.

If you grow some on to find out categorically then post back with leaves.

Edit: I think they are black sesame (Sesamum indicum); there is a black variety. Warning! Do not eat one to find out, I could easily be wrong and don't want to be held liable!!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like red yucca seeds to me. They grow well down here in Arizona and you can find many within lantern-like pods.

Comment: It's an interesting suggestion, Patti, while the colour black is right I think the size and shape are wrong. The fruits on red yucca produce seeds like segments in an orange, with a curvy side and a somewhat straight edge as a result of sharing space with others in a round fruit. Also the [seeds are about an inch](https://www.wildflower.org/plants/result.php?id_plant=hepa8) or more long, much larger than those pictured above.

Comment: Ahhh, yes Colin, I think you are right on both counts of shape and size. As I look closely at the picture the seeds do have a flatter end as if they’ve been attached and are otherwise somewhat elliptical in shape and about a forth smaller than red yucca. Thanks for your insights!